# Can I bake a wireframe to a texture map?

Tags: texture-baking, wireframe

I applied subdivide smooth three times(via specials menu) to a body mesh I'm working on, back to object mode, switch to wireframe display (with display all edges disabled), then Blender shows the mesh the way in the picture.

I find this display result could be a good start point to add some details to my character's body texture (yet to be made). So can I bake this kind of information (really no idea how to call it) on this mesh to an image texture?

[image: mesh display]

Comment: I think "all edges disabled" is the trickiest part of whole thing. Easy solution I see is to make highres OpenGL render from desired view and map it onto UV unwrapped mesh from exactly same view ("UV project from view"). Then bake projected texture to proper UV map. You should get some sort of seam, where two textures will meet (front view and back view). But it could be possibly removed with texture painting.